# Passing arrays by value in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a Rust function defined as

```
fn foo(array: [u32; 100]) {
    // ...
}
```

When calling this function, how is the argument being passed? Is the whole array actually being "passed by value" (copied on the stack), since the array's type implements the Copy trait?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the `Copy` trait: `array: [String; 100]` will also be passed by value even though `String` is not `Copy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When calling this function, how is the argument being passed? Is the whole array actually being "passed by value" (copied on the stack), since the array's type implements the Copy trait?

I assume you mean `[u32; 100]`. And yes, that is passing by value.

If this is undesirable you can use a `Box<[u32; 100]>` or just a `Vec<u32>`. Or if you simply wish to read/mutate the array rather than take ownership you can take a slice (`&[u32]`) or mutable slice (`&mut [u32]`) respectively.